# A physical interpretation of a very known elliptical PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, linear-pde

I am looking for some reference that deals with applications; in real life, of the very known elliptical equation
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
-\Delta u(x) + u(x) &= f(x), x \in \Omega \\
 u(x) &= 0,  x \in \partial \Omega
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
$$
For example, in one dimensional case, taking $\Omega = (a,b)$, what would an application of it in real life?  Tha is, what does the equation
$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
-u''(x) + u(x) &= f(x), x \in (a,b) \\
 u(a) = u(b) &= 0
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
$$
represents physically?

Comment: One element of answer is $-\Delta +V$ is the energy operator in quantum physics. (Here $V=1$)

Comment: The equation $\triangle u= - u +f$ is the vibrating drumhead model, so I wonder if you really intend to write $\triangle u= u+f$, which differs by a minus sign from that model?

Comment: I really wanted the equation like a wrote, because it is very common in PDE courses. But the equation $\Delta u - u = f$ works for me. If you know something about it, please, tell me.

Comment: The most common elliptic pde in introductory courses that comes closest to your query is the vibrating drum model ($\triangle u= - u+ f$). That is why I am puzzled by the wording in your post.   Note that there are no nontrivial real solutions to the homogeneous equation $u_{xx}= u$ with the boundary conditions you have specified.

Comment: FYI. Also the answer you accepted below appears to describe the vibrating drum model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, for a surface u(x,y), e.g. water/air  $\Delta u$  is the surface tension energy density. By integration over a small circle it  results into  the force on the boundary of a circle. The result is an accelerating net force plus a radial force on the circle trying to flatten local humps, that enlarge the surface area and represent energy concentration areas.

The linear term $u$ is the force back to the 0-level, consider the surface as thee free surface of a system of communicating tubes in a gravitional field.

The inhomogenous term $f$ represents external forces independent of the local amplitude  $u$, eg variing gravitational fields or air pressure.

The universality  of these three terms for many different phenomena rests in the fact, that $\Delta$ is  the euclidean mean operator in a small neighborhood $x \pm dx$ for small deviations from equipartition for time evolutions, eg in dimension 1

$$u_{t+dt}(x)  = u_t(x) + dt \  \frac{1}{2} \ (u_t(x+dx)+u_t(x-dx)-2 u_t(x)) = u_t(x) (1-dt\  dx) +  \ dt \  \frac{1}{2} ( u_t(x+dx) + u_t(x-dx)) $$